# GuestBook PHP Script advice

Tags: php, html

I'm making a simple guestbook script in php. I pretty much have it finished but need help finding the logic errors in my code. One is that when echoing the results from the form content. I am wanting to display the email, whole name and comment, each on different lines.

like this

```
email: some@email.com
Name: joe somebody
Comment:
hello  world.
```

but for some reason it just displays the first and last name on all lines.

the other 3 issues are sorting(ascending, descending) and removing duplicates.

Thanks in advance for your advice on how to fix this.

I just ask you be detailed so i know what you are talking about.

In any case, heres the code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>        
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Guest Book</title>
     </head>
     <body>                                                                            
     <?php
        // is there data in the fields 
         if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $firstName = addslashes($_POST['first_name']);                         
         $lastName = addslashes($_POST['last_name']); 
         $wholeName = $firstName . "," . $lastName;

         $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
         $comment = addslashes($_POST['comment']);

         $guestRecord = "$wholeName~$email~$comment\n";
         $guestBook = fopen("guestbook.txt", "ab"); 

         //if not let the user know
         if ($guestBook === FALSE)           
         echo "There was an error saving your entry!\n";      
         else {  
         // if there is info add it to the txt file        
         fwrite($guestBook, $guestRecord);           
         // close the txt file
         fclose($guestBook);
         //let the user know info was saved      
         echo "Your entry has been saved.\n";      
         } 
         }       
         ?>
         <h2>Enter your name to sign our guest book</h2> 
       <hr>      
         <form method="POST" action ="GuestBook1.php">                            
        <p>First Name<input type ="text" name="first_name"/></p>                     
        <p>Last Name<input type ="text" name="last_name"/></p> 
        <p>Email<input type ="text" name="email"/></p>
        <p><textarea name="comment" id="comment"/></textarea></p>
        <p><input type ="submit" value ="Submit"      name="submit"/></p>                             
    </form>     
     <hr>   

     <p><a href ="GuestBook.php">Show Guest Book</a>  
     <br />
      <a href="GuestBook.php?action=Delete%20First">Delete Guest Entry</a>
      <br />
      <a href="GuestBook.php?action=Remove%20Duplicates">Remove Duplicate Entries</a>
      <br />
      <a href="GuestBook.php?action=Sort%20Ascending">Sort Entries A-Z</a>
      <br />
      <a href="GuestBook.php?action=Sort%20Descending">Sort Entries Z-A</a>
      <br />
    </p>

        <?php
         // if theres info in the form process info
        if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
              if ((file_exists("guestbook.txt")) &&
                  (filesize("guestbook.txt") != 0)) {
                  $guestArray = file("guestbook.txt");
                  //switch to $_Get Method 
                  switch ($_GET['submit']) {                       
               // remove duplicate entries
            case 'Remove Duplicates':      
            $guestArray = array_unique($guestRecord);      
            $guestArray = array_values($guestRecord);      
            break;
            //sort ascending
              case 'Sort Ascending':
              $guestArray = sort($guestArray);
                    break;  
               //sort Decending
              case 'Sort Decending':
              $guestArray = ksort($guestArray);
              break;                              
                 }            
                  //count to see how many entries there are              
                  if (count($guestArray)>0) {
                  $newGuest = implode($guestArray); 
                  $guestStore = fopen("guestbook.txt", "ab");  
                  if ($guestStore === false)
                  echo "There was an error updating the message file\n";                
                  else {fwrite($guestStore, $newGuest);
                  fclose($guestStore);
                        }           
                                        }           
                                        else
                                        unlink("guestbook.txt");} 
                                        } 
                                        if ((!file_exists("guestbook.txt")) || 
                                        (filesize("guestbook.txt") == 0))      
                                        echo "<p>There are no entries.</p>\n"; 
                                        else {
        // there isnt anything in the txt file show an error                                
        if ((!file_exists("guestbook.txt")) || 
        (filesize("guestbook.txt") == 0))      
        echo "<p>There are no entries.</p>\n"; else {
        //if there is information display the txt file in a table       
        $guestArray = file("guestbook.txt");      
        echo "<table style=\"background-color:lightgray\" 
        border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">\n";      

        //begin counting number of guest entries
        $count = count($guestArray);      
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $currMsg = explode("~", $guestArray[$i]);      
        // display results in a table    
        echo "<td width=\"5%\" style=\"text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold\">" . ($i + 1) . "</td>\n"; 
             echo "<td width=\"95%\"><span style=\"font-weight:bold\">
                 Email:</span> " . htmlentities($currMsg[0]) . "<br />\n";
                 echo "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">Name:</span> " .         
                   htmlentities($currMsg[0]) . "<br />\n";
                           echo "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline; 
                           font-weight:bold\">Comment</span><br />\n" .
                           htmlentities($currMsg[0]) .  
                           "</td>\n";      
                           echo "</tr>\n"; 
                           }      
                           echo "</table>\n";
                           }
                                               }
        ?>                                                                        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you talk about sorting, what do you want to sort them by? Name (first or last)? Email? Comment? Something else?

Comment: a db would be a million times easer than a flat file

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstName = addslashes($_POST['first_name'])."\r\n";
```

The `\r\n\` will put things physically on a new line. Make sure to use double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your first issue, you are echoing `$currMsg[0]` for all of the fields. You need to use the correct index for each of the values (`0` for name, `1` for email, `2` for comment). Or even better, use something like:

```
list($name, $email, $comment) = explode("~", $guestArray[$i]);
```

That way you have meaningful variable names.

The other issues you'll need to be more specific as to what you're trying to do (and in what way your current code isn't working).

I can see at least one issue though - your links have `?action=` but your `switch` statement is looking at `$_GET['submit']`, not `$_GET['action']`. Plus you have a typo in `case 'Sort Decending':` (missing 's')